# Conversion between Option[F[ShoppingCart]] to F[Option[ShoppingCart]]

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect, tagless-final

I have the following algebra in Scala (I am using the Tagless Final Pattern):

```scala
trait ShoppingCarts[F[_]] {
  def create(id: String): F[Unit]
  def find(id: String): F[Option[ShoppingCart]]
  def add(sc: ShoppingCart, product: Product): F[ShoppingCart]
}
```

Using the above algebra, I created the following program:

```scala
def createAndToCart[F[_] : Monad : ShoppingCarts](product: Product, cartId: String): F[Option[ShoppingCart]] =
  for {
    _ <- ShoppingCarts[F].create(cartId)
    maybeSc <- ShoppingCarts[F].find(cartId)
    maybeNewScF = maybeSc.map(sc => ShoppingCarts[F].add(sc, product))
    maybeNewSc <- maybeNewScF match {
      case Some(d) => d.map(s1 => Option.apply(s1))
      case _ => Monad[F].pure(Option.empty[ShoppingCart])
    }
  } yield maybeNewSc
```

I don't like the code very much in the *for-comprehension* construct that converts an `Option[F[ShoppingCart]]` into an `F[Option[ShoppingCart]]`. I know for sure that I can do better, but I don't know how to improve it.

I am using Cats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `traverse` and `sequence`. What these functions do is "switch" the order of effects, so they are able to change `G[F[A]]` to `F[G[A]]` if G has an instance of `Applicative`. `Option` has such an instance in scope, so you'd be able to use it.

`traverse` takes additional mapping function, but if you just want to "switch" effect, so `sequence` will be way to go:

```
for {
      _ <- ShoppingCarts[F].create(cartId)
      maybeSc <- ShoppingCarts[F].find(cartId)
      maybeNewSc <- maybeSc.map(sc => ShoppingCarts[F].add(sc, product)).sequence //here you need to use sequence
} yield maybeNewSc
```

or you can merge `map` and `sequence` into one step with `traverse`:

```
for {
      _ <- ShoppingCarts[F].create(cartId)
      maybeSc <- ShoppingCarts[F].find(cartId)
      maybeNewSc <- maybeSc.traverse(sc => ShoppingCarts[F].add(sc, product))
} yield maybeNewSc
```

You can read more on `sequence` and `traverse` in [cats docs](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/traverse.html).

Another thing I would suggest you is checking out are [monad transformers](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/optiont.html) since they're making dealing with nested monads stacks like `F[Option[A]]`  a lot easier.

Comment: Please, can you add the needed imports from the Cats library?

Comment: If you're using the relatively new version of cats, you can use `import cats.syntax.all._`.